# Is there a way in TypeScript to check if a string contains Interpolations[is a Template String]?

Tags: typescript, interpolation, template-strings

I have a method where, if its parameters contain **interpolation** it should replace them.

If not, it should go with the basic string.

```
 private logsState(param?: any) {
  let action = param.startsWith("`") ? this.tagService.tag(param) : param;

 // some logging
}
```

If I call the method with a parameter like below:

```
`load my offers success with data ${[{"id":"123","temp":null}]}`
```

As you can see I am checking if the param is starting with (`) or not (as for Tagged Templates), but I think because of the compilation of **TypeScript** to JavaScript the result will contain the **interpolation** as [object], while it should be in the **JSON** format.

Is there any good way to check if a string is a **template string** or not?

I would really appreciate it if anybody could help.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. A template string isn't a thing in and of itself, you couldn't pass it around and "fill in the blanks" later, either in ES6 or TS. It's just a way of building a string with values interpolated from the current scope, unless you're using *tags* (see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: I see. Thanks for the reference, I am new to typescript, therefore, I do not know that much about this stuff. @jonrsharpe